# on the real part of a toric variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, toric-geometry, toric-varieties

Corresponding to a strongly convex rational polyhedral cone $\sigma$ in the lattice $N$ we have the affine toric variety $U_\sigma=\operatorname{Hom_{semi group}}(\sigma^\vee\cap M,\mathbb C)$ where $M$ is the dual lattice.

Fulton, defines the real part of this variety as $(U_\sigma)_\mathbb R=\operatorname{Hom_{semi group}}(\sigma^\vee\cap M,\mathbb R)$.

Now if $N=\mathbb Z^2$ with $e_1,e_2$ as the standard basis and $\sigma=\mathbb R_{\ge0}e_1+\mathbb R_{\ge0}e_2$ the $U_\sigma$ can be identified with $\mathbb C^2$ by the map  $$(\chi^{e_1},\chi^{e_2}):U_\sigma\to\mathbb C^2\quad\text{ which sends}\quad u\mapsto(u(e_1),u(e_2))$$

This basically comes from identifying $\mathbb C[x,y]$ with $\mathbb C[\chi^{e_1},\chi^{e_2}]$ and taking $\operatorname{Maxspec}$. However one can't do the same thing with $(U_\sigma)_\mathbb R$ as $\mathbb R$ is not  algebraically closed. So in that case,

**What would $(U_\sigma)_\mathbb R$ look like?**

Thank you.

Comment: Can you describe the semigroup $\sigma^\vee\cap M$ in that case? Do it by generators and relations.

Comment: $\sigma^\vee\cap M=\mathbb Z_{\ge0}e_1+\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}e_2$

Comment: And are there relations between those two generators?

Comment: One you know that, then it is easy to find all semigroup homomorphosms $\sigma^\vee\cap M\to\mathbb R$. Do it :-)

Comment: The semigroup homomorphisms are just given by where they send the generators to and by sending $0$ to $1$. Also there are no relations between the generators so they can be sent to any pair of real numbers. Thus $(U_\sigma)_\mathbb R$ should be $\mathbb R^2$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$